# Getting in to smart card programming

Tags: hardware, information

I have a [Compaq nw8440](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12449_div/12449_div.HTML#Standard%20Features) with a smart card reader that is:

> Compatible with ISO 7816 compliant Smart Cards. PC/SC interface support

I have been interested in smart cards and wanted to start playing around with them. If I wanted to get in to programming smart cards where can I find resources on how to do it, and would I need any additional hardware other than what my laptop provides (besides the cards to program)?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Java Card platform to start. It's a subset of Java that allows one to write smart card applications. Also, you will need some blank cards to play with. A card reader and software should be enough to get you going.

Good luck!